# Python: Multiple dataframes from multiple CSV, encoding cp1252 to utf8

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I have a zipfile of several CSV documents. I have extracted the CSV's into a folder called "staging." These documents are encoded in Windows CP1252. What I would like to do is read in each CSV file individually as a separate dataframe and then overwrite the old files with utf8 encoding after I have removed all of the null values. Or instead of rewriting the CSVs to utf8 I can encode the database strictly from the pandas dataframes that are produced. Any help would be greatly appreciated- I have browsed the Stack Overflow forums and the main topic seems to be concatenating multiple CSV's into a single dataframe- what I need is a separate dataframe for each CSV. Also, I have to remove N/A values, however, in the CSV's they have random numbers attached to them (ie- N/A (3) or N/A(1), etc)

Here is the code I am working with:

```
# Create the staging directory
staging_dir = "staging"
os.mkdir(staging_dir)

# Confirm the staging directory path
os.path.isdir(staging_dir)

# Machine independent path to create files
zip_file = os.path.join(staging_dir, "Hospital_Revised_Flatfiles.zip")

# Write the files to the computer
zf = open(zip_file,"wb")
zf.write(r.content)
zf.close()

# Program to unzip the files
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file,"r")
z.extractall(staging_dir)
z.close()

#Create the dataframes

import io
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(os.path.join("staging" + "/*.csv"))

# OS independent reading of files
for file in files:
    dfs = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0, encoding = 'cp1252')
```

Comment: If you are planning to rewrite the data frames back into separate files, why concatenate them in the first place?

Comment: @COLDSPEED exactly, I do not want to concatenate them at all, I would like to keep them separate, but I dont know how to import each CSV file into a separate dataframe and when I try I get an unexpected EOF syntax error.

Comment: SyntaxError? On which line?

Comment: I was getting a syntax error because on the last line, as @P.Tillmann pointed out- I had an extra bracket. I removed the bracket and no longer get the syntax error but the code is only producing a single dataframe. I need a separate dataframe for each csv in the folder "staging"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe P.Tillmann's solution should've worked. Alternatively, you can load all your dataframes first and *then* write them back.

```
files = glob.glob(os.path.join("staging" + "/*.csv"))

dict_ = {}
for file in files:
    dict_[file] = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, encoding='cp1252').dropna()

for file in dict_:
    dict_[file].to_csv(file, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED this method seems to have worked in that it created the dataframes but I ran it once without the .dropna() and noticed that the dictionaries had more columns in them with NaN's (perhaps it is concatenating the column headers and putting them in all dictionaries?). I reran the code with .dropna() and it seems to have frozen my editor. Not sure whats going on here.

Comment: @zsad512 Yes, you're right. What happens with dropna() is that it just kills entire rows with `nan` values. If you want to substitute those NaNs with something harmless, you can change `dropna` to `fillna(0)` which replaces NaNs with 0s. Alternatively, if you use text data, use `fillna('')`. If it works as you wish, please consider marking this answer accepted :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED -  I am trying to work out some kinks in this code and then I will mark the answer as accepted. Upon examining individual spreadsheets at random, I have noticed that aside from the dropna issue- some of the data is not being imported. For example, in one spreadsheet I have 4 columns with floating point numbers in them as "denominator","score","lower estimate","higher estimate" all of these columns have been filled with "Not Available". How can I work around this issue? What I would like to do is import all information in all CSV's as string values

Comment: @zsad512 For your first query, check your delimiters. That's most likely the issue. Also, You can add a `dtype=str` argument when calling `read_csv`, like this:  `pd.read_csv(file, header=0, dtype=str, encoding='cp1252').fillna('')`

Comment: @COLDSPEED- one issue I am having is that the null values in the spreadsheets are not actually always null. In some spreadsheets they are filled as N/A(1), N/A(3) N/A(5), etc

Comment: @COLDSPEED- how do I check the delimiters? One issue I am having is that I mispoke. What I need to do is remove any "nulls" (that were most likely created from concatenation of excel files in windows) and the N/A(#) values can be left as they are.

Comment: @zsad512 Check your csv files and make sure they are separated by commas. If not, you need to explicitly set the `delimiter` attribute in `read_csv`. Also, if you want to remove those nulls, take a look at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna

Comment: @COLDSPEED perhaps you can help me with my next issue: 'code' for file in dict_: dict_[file].rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'), inplace=True) 'code' returns a "key error: 'Value of care measure name'" and also "ERROR: Execution aborted"

Comment: @zsad512 I can but, bit busy atm, so won't be able to respond. I would recommend opening a new question :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I dont have enough reputation to ask another question for some days now :(

Comment: Make another account?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
dfs.dropna().to_csv(file, encoding='utf-8')
```

to your last loop. It will drop all rows with null values and then save the dataframe by overwriting the old version.

And remove the first bracket in your last line, you open two but only close one. Thats where the EOF error is coming from.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the extra bracket, however, this method does not work. Some of the files were completely overwritten and I ended up with blank CSVs. Some files were unchanged. The dataframe that is produced is a single dataframe that is 30 x 5. What I want is a seperate dataframe for each CSV. Also, I think that instead of writing the CSV's back as UTF8 can be skipped if I can use the pandas dataframes to create my sqlite db

Comment: Well you can certainly use the dataframes to build a sqlite database but I'm surprised that the code is not working for you because it runs fine for me. Is your csv coma seperated?

Comment: I am not sure of the formatting of the CSV's they are actually excel workbooks with CP1252 encoding and I am trying to open them in python as CSV's. The corrections you made seemed to have worked for me as well. It was not until I randomly inspected select workbooks in excel that I noticed SOME were now blank except for the headers.